# Posicionar tabela criada dinamicamente com DIV

Tags: javascript

Criei uma tabela dinamicamente. Quero criar dinamicamente divs, para poder posicionar cada uma dos circulos e legendas.

exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/tttxfvcu/17/

Comment: Por que não cria dois divs? Em um, você coloca o gráfico e no outro a legenda, fica mais simples tratar as posições com CSS. É alguma particularidade desse `raphael.js` criar tudo em um div?

Comment: Pode-se separar em várias divs. Tem é de se criar dinamicamente, cada vez que chama uma função.

Comment: Como posso criar as div para esse exemplo?

Comment: Tem várias formas, eu particularmente prefiro optar pelo uso de [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) para não ficar me preocupando muito com posicionamento. Ficaria mais ou menos assim: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re22/z2ns10uq/), eu até criaria uma resposta mas não sei como funciona esse `raphael.js`.